# Jasny-Bootstrap reveal menu breaks navbar-collapse and navbar-toggle functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When I use [this example from jasny-bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/) and add items to the navbar while using the `navbar-toggle` and `navbar-collapse` with two `navbar-nav` lists that use `navbar-left` and `navbar-right` it breaks the `navbar` entirely in `desktop` view.

The `navbar-toggle` appears at `desktop` resolution at the left of the `navbar` and `navbar-nav` items are rendered haphazardly both to the `left` and `right` of the `navbar`.

However all of this works at `mobile` and `tablet` resolutions although the `navbar-toggle` remains at the left of the `navbar` beside the navmenu.

I understand that this is because `jasny-bootstrap` uses `navbar-toggle`.So,what `css` would I need to copy/use from the `bootstrap` `css`(with a different class name ofcourse) and `js` in order to restore `navbar-toggle` functionality to the `navbar`?

[This is a fiddle with my existing code](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/f5kg9auc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional CSS shows the `.navbar-toggle` for all viewports. Simply modify it to only show the button for revealing the navmenu.

#### HTML

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-reveal" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="false" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas">
```

#### CSS

```
@media (min-width: 0) {
  .navbar-toggle-reveal {
    display: block; /* force showing the toggle */
  }
}
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5kg9auc/2/)

Comment: I moved the toggle for navbar items(pancake button) to the right,[this is exactly what I wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/f5kg9auc/4/)